# PYTHON: Appending unicode to list changes its type to str

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, flask

This is my scenario:
I have a list of Unicode strings. I receive a utf8 string named 'input' and want to log it with the rest of the elements in the list. So I decode it and get a Unicode object, but when I append it to the list, its type changes to "str". What is happening here?

```
a_list = [u"ááááá", u"eééééée"]
#'input' is a utf8 str
obj = input.decode("utf-8")
log.debug(type(obj))
log.debug(obj)
a_list.append(obj)
for elem in a_list:
    log.debug(type(elem))
```

Log:

```
DEBUG - <type 'unicode'>' # obj
<(THIS IS ONLY FOR SIMPLIFY) obj with accents (unicode chars)>
DEBUG - <type 'unicode'>'
DEBUG - <type 'unicode'>'
DEBUG - <type 'str'>'   # ------> obj's type changed!!!
```

EDIT: Python 2.7.3

input is "request.data" from a request object in Flask microframework

Comment: What's the Python version? I've tested this under Python 2.7.3 and can't reproduce this behavior. Where does `input` come from? `log.debug(obj)` gives strange output as for unicode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way this happens as you say. Here is code that reproduces your behavior:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
a_list = [u"ááááá", u"eééééée"]
input = '\xc3\x85 i \xc3\xa5a \xc3\xa4 e \xc3\xb6'
obj = input.decode("utf-8")
print type(obj)
print obj
a_list.append(obj)
for elem in a_list:
    print type(elem)
```

And here is the output:

```
<type 'unicode'>
Å i åa ä e ö
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
```

Some of the objects involved must be other than the builtin types, that make this conversion happen.

Unless you simply add `input` to the list where you meant to add `obj`. :-)

Comment: OMG I am really sorry... typo in my code was driving me crazy... should I delete the question?

Comment: @lennart-regebro, thanks for confirming conclusions from my small investigation (see my comment to the question). I've made a similar test code to reproduce strange behavior and I was suspecting that `input` was not what OP thought it was.